# como comparar un numero random con el usuario?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int computer = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
        int user = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

ya hice una parte del codigo,como establecer la libraria de matematicas con el generador random y hacer el clase de Scanner, pero mi pregunta es como yo puedo comparar el numero random con el usuario. como tambien hacer una iteracion hasta que el usuario digite un numero negativo y terminar el codigo. alguien me pueda explicar como hacerlo, se los agradeceria un monton. soy nuevo en Java.

Comment: Pues tomas el dato del usuario, lo vuelves del mismo tipo que el aleatorio y los comparas.

Comment: Aunque seas nuevo debes mostrar esfuerzo antes que te podamos responder. No es tan difícil. Es cuestión de que sepas razonar y cosas básicas del lenguaje.

Comment: ya intentaste... usando operadores de comparación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int computer = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
```

Primer problema lógico, si debo comparar con el número que
indique el usuario, no tiene sentido instanciar **`user`** con
un número aleatorio, lo instancio con la entrada del usuario,
que obtengo con `nextInt()`.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int user = input.nextInt();
```

El objeto de la clase `Scanner` (**`input`**), tiene el método
`nextInt()` que devuelve el número que el usuario escribe
en la consola.

bien, tengo dos números, usando un bloque `if / else if / else`,
procedo a compararlos.

```
    if( computer < user ) {
        System.out.println( "Gano User" );
    }
    else if( computer == user ) {
        System.out.println( "Empate" );
    }
    else {
        System.out.println( "Gano Computer" );
    }
```

el `if / else if / else`, es un bloque de decisión, osea, si la
condición (lo que está entre paréntesis), es verdadera, ejecuto
el código que está entre llaves.
Hay que tener en cuenta, que así como están, son excluyentes,
osea, si entra en el `if`, sin importar la condición del `else if`
no va a entrar en el, y solo entrará en el `else`, si no ha
entrado el los anteriores.

Comparadores: -------------- esto devolverá verdadero:

```
numA < numB   // -> si numA es menor que numB.  
numA > numB   // -> si numA mayor que numB.  
numA == numB  // -> si son iguales, no confundir con = que es de asignación.  
numA != numB  // -> si no son iguales.  
numA <= numB  // -> si es menor o igual.  
numA >= numB  // -> si es mayor o igual.  
textoA.equals( textoB )  // -> si las dos cadenas son iguales
```

Ya tenemos la toma de dato y la comparación listas, nos queda hacer que el programa se repita, hasta que el usuario ingrese un número negativo.
Para esto vamos a usar un bucle, un do-while, un bucle es una sección de código, que se repite mientras la condición del mismo sea verdadera, por ejemplo:

```
int numero = 0;
while( numero < 5 ) {  
       // mientras numero sea menor que 5, todo esto se va a ejecutar
    hagoAlgo();

       // la siguiente linea, nos saca del bucle, ya que con cada 
       // iteración, aumenta el valor de numero, por lo que si o si,
       // llegará el momento en que sea igual a 5, por lo tanto la       
       // condición numero < 5 no se cumple, y se sale del bucle.  
    numero = numero + 1;
}
```

Pero como dije, vamos a usar el `do-while`, que es una variante del `while`,
en la que se asegura que el código se ejecute al menos una vez.

```
int numero = 0;
do {  
    hagoAlgo();
    numero = numero + 1;
}
while( numero < 5 );
```

Ahora lo aplicamos a tu problema:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
  Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
  int user;
  System.out.println( "Ingresa un número entero positivo, si quires probar suerte\n"
          + "o uno negativo si quieres salir" );
  do {
     user = input.nextInt();
     if( user > 0 ) {
        int computer = (int) ( Math.random() * 101 );

        if( computer < user ) {
           System.out.println( "Gano User" );
        }
        else if( computer == user ) {
           System.out.println( "Empate" );
        }
        else {
           System.out.println( "Gano Computer" );
        }
        System.out.println( "Ingresa otro número entero positivo, si quires seguir\n"
                + "o uno negativo si quieres salir" );
     }
  }
  while( user > 0 );
```

Como vez, tuve que hacer unas modificaciones:
Solo deje fuera del `do`, la declaración (sin instanciar) de **`user`**, la creación del objeto `Scanner`, y un primer mensaje para el usuario.
Luego, dentro del `do`, instancio **`user`** con la entrada del usuario, con un `if`, verifico que **`user`** sea mayor que `0`, si lo es, instancio **`computer`** con un aleatorio, hago las comparaciones pertinentes, y vuelvo a generar un mensaje para el usuario.
En cualquier momento que el usuario ingrese un valor negativo, se deja de cumplir **`user > 0`** y se sale del programa.
Si te queda alguna duda, no dudes en preguntar.